# Change Bower package name to lowercase

Tags: bower

Once upon a time I published my library "ScrollMagic" for bower.
For lack of knowledge and proper reading (shame on me) I did not adhere to the "lowercase only" naming convention.

With version 2.0.0 i [changed that](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/blob/25cbdccd5dd57a14c88f4396aa690d20308123a5/bower.json#L2) and now it's all lowercase.

How do I go about fixing that?
Removing "ScrollMagic" is likely to cause problems with people who already set it as a dependency.
But I can't publish as "scrollmagic" because it says the package already exists.

What do I do?

Comment: Usually js/npm/bower conventions to use dash to separate words on package names instead of capital letters. I'm not sure if you want it but you could publish a new package called *scroll-magic*.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but it seems the bower team took care of it. The package is now available via `scrollmagic` and `ScrollMagic`...

Comment: Yeah, just saw it, I was following the thread ;) Good thing to know that apparently can re-assign a package. I'll probably need that in the future. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone interested, here's the corresponding issue on GitHub: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1751